# In SQL, how can I pivot a table and also get the details information?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, pivot

I have the following TSQL test data:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.emp') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE dbo.emp;
CREATE TABLE dbo.emp (name NVARCHAR(10), dept NVARCHAR(10));
GO

INSERT INTO dbo.emp (name, dept)
VALUES
(N'user1', N'dept1'),
(N'user2', N'dept1'),
(N'user3', N'dept2'),
(N'user4', N'dept2'),
(N'user5', N'dept2'),
(N'user6', N'dept3');
```

How can I pivot the data and also get the details of each row? The result I want is:

```
+-------+-------+-------+
| dept1 | dept2 | dept3 |
+-------+-------+-------+
| user1 | user3 | user6 |
| user2 | user4 | NULL  |
| NULL  | user5 | NULL  |
+-------+-------+-------+
```

Right now I've come up with this query:

```
WITH
    cte1 AS (
                SELECT name                              dept1,
                       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY name) row
                FROM dbo.emp
                WHERE
                    dept = 'dept1'
            ),
    cte2 AS (
                SELECT name                              dept2,
                       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY name) row
                FROM dbo.emp
                WHERE
                    dept = 'dept2'
            ),
    cte3 AS (
                SELECT name                              dept3,
                       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY name) row
                FROM dbo.emp
                WHERE
                    dept = 'dept3'
            )
SELECT cte1.dept1,
       cte2.dept2,
       cte3.dept3
FROM cte1
     FULL OUTER JOIN cte2
         ON cte2.row = cte1.row
     FULL OUTER JOIN cte3
         ON cte3.row = cte1.row;
```

This gives me the correct result. However, when I change the demo data to:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.emp') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE dbo.emp;
CREATE TABLE dbo.emp (name NVARCHAR(10), dept NVARCHAR(10));
GO

INSERT INTO dbo.emp (name, dept)
VALUES
(N'user1', N'dept1'),
(N'user2', N'dept1'),
(N'user3', N'dept2'),
(N'user4', N'dept2'),
(N'user5', N'dept2'),
(N'user6', N'dept3'),
(N'user7', N'dept3'),
(N'user8', N'dept3');
```

The aftermentioned query gives:

```
+-------+-------+-------+
| dept1 | dept2 | dept3 |
+-------+-------+-------+
| user1 | user3 | user6 |
| user2 | user4 | user7 |
| NULL  | user5 | NULL  |
| NULL  | NULL  | user8 |
+-------+-------+-------+
```

Which is not what I want. The result I'm expecting is:

```
+-------+-------+-------+
| dept1 | dept2 | dept3 |
+-------+-------+-------+
| user1 | user3 | user6 |
| user2 | user4 | user7 |
| NULL  | user5 | user8 |
+-------+-------+-------+
```

Note the user names are ordered in each column. Hope someone can point me the right direction.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This only handles 3 columns if your dept list is dynamic # then we have to use dynamic SQL to handle the `n` number of columns...  But as you hardcoded 3 in your example, 3 I assumed.

[Demo](https://rextester.com/RNAEP68392) uses rank() but row_number works too; edge cases may produce different results with each however.

I Didn't consider edge cases like if you have duplicate user names in the same departments in your data... Would those get merged into 1 or do you want to see multiple lines or is that not possible with the data?

The use of max and grouping by the row_number is what gives us the non-null rows. 
as to why.. each row number will be unique to each name within a department.  edge cases could cause problems however since the row number is being assigned based on ordered users in departments all the like rows will get merged into one.

You don't need the multiple cte's we can just partition by dept. 
The order by on the names within the partition ensures the names are ordered alphabetically.  then we sort by the row number at the end. .

```
CREATE TABLE emp53564443 (name NVARCHAR(10), dept NVARCHAR(10));

INSERT INTO emp53564443 (name, dept)
VALUES
(N'user1', N'dept1'),
(N'user2', N'dept1'),
(N'user3', N'dept2'),
(N'user4', N'dept2'),
(N'user5', N'dept2'),
(N'user6', N'dept3'),
(N'user7', N'dept3'),
(N'user8', N'dept3');

with cte as (SELECT A.*
                 , row_number() over (partition by dept order by name) RnDEPT
             FROM emp53564443 A)

SELECT max(Case when dept='dept1' then name end) dept1
     , max(case when dept='dept2' then name end) dept2
     , max(case when dept='dept3' then name end) dept3
FROM cte
GROUP BY rnDept
ORDER BY rnDept
```

Giving us:

```
+---+-------+-------+-------+
|   | dept1 | dept2 | dept3 |
+---+-------+-------+-------+
| 1 | user1 | user3 | user6 |
| 2 | user2 | user4 | user7 |
| 3 | NULL  | user5 | user8 |
+---+-------+-------+-------+
```

Comment: Thanks for the smart solution.